# How to write comments over a specific segment of text?

Tags: vertical-alignment

I have a number 9999...99955 and I would like to specify how many 9s there are in total by writing over the number using brackets to segment the text. Like this [image]

Comment: You can use`\overbrace{9999\ldots999}^{comment}55`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I compile this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \[{\overbrace{9999\ldots99}^{160\ 9\text{'s}}}55\]
\end{document}
```

I get this:

[image]

Comment: If you wrap the whole `\overbrace` in an additional group you'll get rid of the `\thinmuskip` between the two groups of figures.

Comment: @campa Nice! I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @campa I upvoted the same :-)